# Cannot generate P2 metadata: P2 publisher return code was 13 in WSO2 product-ei install

Tags: wso2

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wso2.maven:carbon-p2-plugin:1.5.8:materialize-product (creating-default-product) on project micro-integrator-p2-profile: Cannot generate P2 metadata: P2 publisher return code was 13 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.wso2.maven:carbon-p2-plugin:1.5.8:materialize-product (creating-default-product) on project micro-integrator-p2-profile: Cannot generate P2 metadata
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit, in what you are trying to achieve and what you have ?

Comment: Dear Julien , Thanks for replay .. my moto is i need to deploye WSO2 product-ei code in to my local for that i run the maven command from root WSO2 root directory ..Result is below failed at P2 generations .

Comment: [INFO] WSO2 MSF4J Runtime ................................. SUCCESS [ 32.350 s]
[INFO] WSO2 Enterprise Integrator - P2 Profile Module ..... SUCCESS [  0.035 s]
[INFO] WSO2 Enterprise Integrator - micro-integrator P2 Profile Generation FAILURE [ 33.353 s]
[INFO] WSO2 Enterprise Integrator - P2 Profile Generation . SKIPPED
[INFO] >WSO2 Enterprise Integrator - Analytics Profile Generation SKIPPED

Answer (score 0):

We have removed the micro-integrator profile from wso2 EI and it is now available as separate runtime, as per the error, I hope you have some code cached in your local repo.

Could you please take a fresh clone of [1] and try to execute

> mvn clean install

Please refer [2] if you encounter any cert issues while building it.

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/tree/master

[2] - https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/pull/779/files

Thanks